# Why I am not able to import anything from . in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa

```py
import warnings

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.ticker import Formatter, ScalarFormatter
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator, FixedLocator, MaxNLocator
from matplotlib.ticker import SymmetricalLogLocator

# I am grtting error in below line lines while importing anything from .
from . import core
from . import util
from .util.exceptions import ParameterError
```

Whereas I want to successfully import core from . in my python project.
But I am grtting this type os error

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
 10 # from . import core
 11 # from . import util
```

---> 12 from .util.exceptions import ParameterError

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.util'; '**main**' is not a package

Comment: have you created an `__init__.py` in this directory?

Comment: yes eqomatic, it is already there in my project.